# In "The World and Thorinn", are the other creatures Thorinn encounters variants of humans?

Tags: the-world-and-thorinn

I recently picked up a copy of Damon Knight's *[The World and Thorinn](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1171823.The_World_and_Thorinn)*, which I vaguely recall reading when I was younger. At the end of the book, some things are explained, such as that

> Thorinn is human. He is not the last human being left, but he is of the lineage of leaders, which qualifies him to give orders to the Monitor. The other races that he encounters are being conserved and bred by the robots under the guidance of The Monitor.

What I don't completely get, is what are the other races that Thorinn encounters? Are they aliens that had been encountered? Mutated humans? Genetic constructs? They certainly cover an extremely wide variety of forms, from troll-like creatures to insectile ones to ones based off of birds and monkeys. But what are they, really? Was it explained in the course of the book?

Comment: Wow, someone really didn't like the book: https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/damon-knight-4/the-world-and-thorinn/

Comment: @DavidW: Yup. Not to everyone's tastes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book shares Damon Francis Knight's sarcastic view of human attempts at progress, using different races of peoples very much the way Jonathan Swift did in Gulliver's Travels. Each race is essentially an anthropomorphized human quality in a purified form, corrupted as Thorrin voyages through their worlds. This is a typical [urbane and darkly humorous short story Knight was renowned](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/knight_damon) for. Recall that in the end The Monitor had the duty of keeping humanity safe, and to do this it decided to simply keep all peoples ignorant of each other.

To answer your question, consider the pod people toward the beginning of the book after descending beyond the sky-scythe of Hovenskar. At a point Thorrin is challenged with a waterfall as the only way forward, and experiments with an unopened pod to see if it could serve as a boat. Here is the prose of that effort:

> Another, equally alarming thought: what if the water made the pod open? This, at least, he could find out by trial. He went back to the vine, grasped it above . the closed pod, chopped at it with his sword. The blade rebounded at the first blow, then bit in; a milky sap oozed from the wound. Thorinn smote again, slashed the vine through.
>
> The pod remained closed. Thorinn dragged it down the slope into the water, where it floated sluggishly among the reeds. He sat on a tussock and watched it. For a long time nothing happened. Bored and hungry, he got up and began to forage, coming back frequently to look at the floating pod. At last he found a nest of four speckled greenish eggs in one of the tussocks. He punctured one and sniffed it: it was strong-smelling but fresh. As he was tilting his head to drink the egg out of its shell, he heard a distant splash.
>
> He turned. Nothing was to be seen, but from the direction of the pod came a thrashing sound in the water, then a choked cry. Thorinn dropped the egg and hurried. Before he could reach the spot, he saw a human form flounder upright among the reeds.
>
> It was the boy. He stared wildly at Thorinn, then whirled and tried to run. He fell almost at once in the shallows, but was up again and struggling to the shore. Thorinn saw him reeling up the slope; at the forest's edge, he turned a white face for an instant.

To me this settles the matter, the peoples in these worlds were indeed human. They had a vastly different environment in which to evolve, and so they were quite unique in their forms.

Comment: In the absence of an authoritative answer, yours looks good.